# Standard playing card deck without jokers: Deal 13 cards. What is the probability at least 1 suit is not present?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

Similar questions:

[What is the probability that 13 cards drawn from a standard deck has at least one card from each suit?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123016/what-is-the-probability-that-13-cards-drawn-from-a-standard-deck-has-at-least-on)

[Deal 4 cards from a deck. What is the probability that we get one card from each suit?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211653/deal-4-cards-from-a-deck-what-is-the-probability-that-we-get-one-card-from-each)

---

What I tried:

P(at least 1 suit is not present) = 1 - P(all suits are present)

where

P(all suits are present) =

$$\sum_{a}\sum_{b}\sum_{c}\sum_{d}\frac{\binom{13}{a}\binom{13}{b}\binom{13}{c}\binom{13}{d}}{\binom{52}{13}}$$

where $a+b+c+d=13; a,b,c,d \ge 1$

Is that right? If so, is there a better way to approach this? If not, why?

Following the second question:

$$\frac{\binom{13}{1}^{13}}{\binom{52}{13}}$$

Something else:

$$\frac{\binom{13}{1}^{4} \binom{48}{9}}{\binom{52}{13}}$$

which is ~75 (far greater than 1)

Comment: Hint:  use inclusion-exclusion.  #hands - #hands missing at least one suit +#hands missing at least two suits - #hands missing three suits.

Comment: @lulu thanks ^-^ Is my 4 sum approach wrong though? What exactly is wrong with the last one?

Comment: @d_e I don't understand how it doesn't represent this situation though. I want to pick 1 card from each group of 13. From the unpicked 48 cards, i want to pick 9. I really have to use inc-exc for this?

Comment: @d_e Is there a way to recycle those 48 cards? also the 4 sum approach is wrong?

Comment: I deleted my previous comments. now I understand what you have tried to do and what is your mistake. give me few minutes to write it down.

Comment: @d_e Okay thanks, you can post as answer ^-^

Comment: deleted my answer. it is wrong. but I hope you understand why your calculation is wrong.

Comment: The four sum approach works for the first question (though it is extremely inefficient).  I don't understand your second calculation at all.  I f I am reading correctly, you want to answer the question "if I draw $4$ cards from a deck, what is the probability that I get one from each suit?" Using the same method as you did for the first one that should be $\frac {13^4}{\binom {52}4}\sim .1055$.  Or have I got the question wrong?

Comment: As a variant for the second part (assuming I correctly understand the question):  the first card can be anything.  The second can then only be one of $3\times 13$ cards.  The third can then only be one of $2\times 13$ cards.  And the fourth can then only be one of $13$ cards.  Hence $1\times \frac {39}{51}\times \frac {26}{50}\times \frac {13}{49}$ which, again, is about $.1055$.

Answer (score 3):

Use *inclusion/exclusion* principle:

- Include the number of combinations containing at most $\color\red3$ suits: $\binom{4}{\color\red3}\cdot\binom{\color\red3\cdot13}{13}$
- Exclude the number of combinations containing at most $\color\red2$ suits: $\binom{4}{\color\red2}\cdot\binom{\color\red2\cdot13}{13}$
- Include the number of combinations containing at most $\color\red1$ suit: $\binom{4}{\color\red1}\cdot\binom{\color\red1\cdot13}{13}$

Finally, divide the result by the total number of combinations:

$$\frac{\binom43\cdot\binom{3\cdot13}{13}-\binom42\cdot\binom{2\cdot13}{13}+\binom41\cdot\binom{1\cdot13}{13}}{\binom44\cdot\binom{4\cdot13}{13}}\approx5.1\%$$

Comment: thanks barak manos ^-^ Is my 4 sum approach wrong though? What exactly is wrong with the last one?

Comment: However, $\binom42\binom{3\cdot 13}{13}$ is _not_ the number of combinations with a most 3 suits -- some of them will be double-counted, such as "all the spades", which is counted as both {spades,diamonds,hearts} and {spades,clubs,diamonds} and {spades,clubs,hearts}.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably handled best as an inclusion-exclusion problem, counting the number of hands that omit at least one suit:

Let's take it from the bottom: The number of hands with exactly *one* suit is of course
$$ A_1 = \binom{4}{1} \binom{13}{13} = 4 $$

The number of hands with exactly *two* suits is
$$ A_2 = \binom42 \binom{26}{13} - \binom31 A_1 $$
where the second term corrects for the fact that $\binom42\binom{26}{13}$ counts each of the $4$ one-suit hands three times.

The number of hands with exactly *three* suits is then
$$ A_3 = \binom43 \binom{39}{13} - \binom21 A_2 - \binom32 A_1 $$
where the subtracted terms correct for counting hands that actually contained fewer than three suits.

Now your result would be
$$ 1 - \frac{A_1+A_2+A_3}{\binom{52}{13}} $$

Comment: thanks barak manos ^-^ Is my 4 sum approach wrong though? What exactly is wrong with the last one?